# How do I create a reusable block/proc/lambda in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to create a filter, and be able to apply it to an array or hash.  For example:

```
def isodd(i)
  i % 2 == 1
end
```

The I want to be able to use it like so:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
puts x.select(isodd)
x.delete_if(isodd)
puts x
```

This seems like it should be straight forward, but I can't figure out what I need to do it get it to work.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Create a lambda and then convert to a block with the `&` operator:

```
isodd = lambda { |i| i % 2 == 1 }
[1,2,3,4].select(&isodd)
```

Comment: You may also use the "stabby lambda" operator to create the free standing proc. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340117/what-is-the-stab-operator-in-ruby. Available as of `ruby 1.9`. Of course, purely a matter of taste and coding style :)

Comment: for those reading in future, one can also create lambdas like this:       lambda_name =-> () {puts "hello world"}

Comment: I don't think that lambda is _converted_ to a block, but just _passed_ as the block argument to `select()`.

Answer (score 31):

```
puts x.select(&method(:isodd))
```

Comment: Dave's and Daniel's answers are also good. This is an alternative.

Comment: +1 The answer is useful for when you have an existing method that you don't want to rewrite as a lambda/proc. It also works if the method needs to be called on a specific object: `x.select(&obj.method(:isodd))`

Comment: nice and this correctly answers the question posed - they guy wanted to know how to wrap up an existing method and pass it as a proc

Answer (score 20):

You can create a named `Proc` and pass it to the methods that take blocks:

```
isodd = Proc.new { |i| i % 2 == 1 }
x = [1,2,3,4]
x.select(&isodd) # returns [1,3]
```

The `&` operator converts between a `Proc`/`lambda` and a block, which is what methods like `select` expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this in an instance, and you do not require any other variables outside of the scope of the proc (other variables in the method you're using the proc in), you can make this a frozen constant like so:

```rb
ISODD = -> (i) { i % 2 == 1 }.freeze
x = [1,2,3,4]
x.select(&ISODD)
```

Creating a proc in Ruby is a heavy operation (even with the latest improvements), and doing this helps mitigate that in some cases.