# What is the -> (stab) operator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In the following example:

```
default: -> { Time.now }
```

What's `->`? I am familiar with `=>` but first time I am seeing `->`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It's the Ruby 1.9 "stabby lambda" operator. For example, see [this article from 2008](http://pragdave.me/blog/2008/05/22/new-lambda-syntax-in-ruby-19/).

Nutshell:

```
> foo2 = ->(arg) { arg * 2 }
> foo2.call "now"
 => nownow
```

Note the lack of space between `->` and `(arg)`, that's intentional.

Comment: Actually, I am pretty sure that the space between the `->` and the `(arg)` is not required. Just tried it in `irb` running `ruby 1.9.3p484`. Not sure if the space was required in earlier builds. Or, were you saying "intentional" as a coding style for clarity?

Comment: Ah, oops, I see. When using parens, the space is required, but parents are themselves not required. So `foo2 = -> arg { arg*2 }` would be valid syntax.

Comment: @zealoushacker Correct :-) IMO leaving the parens off is more confusing, but that's less a technical argument then a stylistic one, so I don't bother arguing those.

Comment: (edit) @Chloe not sure what the link was, but the expression uses, as Dave said, the "stabby lambda" operator. It lets you define an anonymous method (see also lambda, Proc.new, etc.). Note that the `-> { #code }` syntax in the original question creates a method with no arguments and could also have been written as `->() { #code }`, which look more like Dave's one argument `->(arg) { #code }` example. This is all completely unrelated to the the Ruby 1.9 hash syntax, despite the unfortunate context. The whole thing could have been written in Ruby 1.8 as `{:default => lambda{ Time.now }}`

Comment: @zealoushacker Re: spacing, ruby 1.9 forbids a space after the arrow if you use parens. E.g. this raises a syntax error: `-> (x) { x }`. The space is allowed in ruby 2.x.