# What does "->" operator in Ruby mean?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the -> (stab) operator in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340117/what-is-the-stab-operator-in-ruby)

I am trying to learn Objects on Rails book and find problem to understand what `->` operator mean.

The code is:

```
describe Blog do
   subject       { Blog.new(->{entries}) }
   let(:entries) { [] }

   it "has no entries" do
     subject.entries.must_be_empty
   end

   describe "#new_entry" do
     let(:new_post) { OpenStruct.new }

   before do
     subject.post_source = ->{ new_post }
   end

   it "returns a new post" do
     subject.new_post.must_equal new_post
   end
end
```

I spend a lot of time to find it in any docs, but couldn't

Comment: FWIW, this is commonly referred to as "stabby lambda".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a [new syntax for lambda](http://pragdave.blogs.pragprog.com/pragdave/2008/05/new-lambda-synt.html). You can also write it like this:

```
subject.post_source = lambda { new_post }
```

Here's how old and new versions look like with parameters (thanks to Michael Kohl for suggestion):

```
v_old = lambda {|a, b| a + b}
v_new = ->(a, b) { a + b}

v_old.call(1, 2) # => 3
v_new.call(3, 4) # => 7
```

Comment: Maybe update your post to show how lambdas with arguments look in both versions.