# What is ->() { } in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've just seen this expression in a Ruby/Rails app:

```
def method(a, b = nil, &c)
   c ||= ->(v) { v }
```

I understand the first part, but not the `->() { ... }` syntax. What does it mean?

The variable names have been changed for briefness. I tried searching, but the non-alphanumeric characters are obviously a nightmare for SEO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the -> (stab) operator in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340117/what-is-the-stab-operator-in-ruby)

Comment: Like the answers have mentioned, it's for creating lambdas. [This is a good article to help you understand them.](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) Incidentally, you can use [SymbolHound](http://www.symbolhound.com/) to search the web for special characters that Google ignores.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a lambda literal. Put the block variables inside `()` and the body inside `{}`.

```
->(x, y){x + y}
```

In the example, `->(v){v}` takes a single argument `v` and returns it, in other words, it is an identity function. If a block is passed to `method`, then that is assigned to `c`. If not, the identity function is assigned to `c` as default.

Comment: So if you're passing in `c` by reference, are you basically just passing in `v` (to a block?) and expecting it back?

Comment: `&c` in ruby does not mean "passed by reference", it means `c` is the proc (aka block) in `method( 'foo' ) do; something; end`

Answer (score 3):

That is a [lambda](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-lambda) literal, introduced in Ruby 1.9:

```
irb> l = ->(v) { v }
# => #<Proc:0x007f4acea30410@(irb):1 (lambda)>
irb> l.call(1)
# => 1
```

It is equivalent to write:

```
irb> l = lambda { |v| v }
# => #<Proc:0x00000001daf538@(irb):1 (lambda)>
```

In the example you posted it is used to provide a default block to the method when none is specified, consider this:

```
def method(a, &c)
  c ||= ->(v) { v }
  c.call(a)
end

method(1)
# => 1
method(1) { |v| v * 2 }
# => 2
```